# -vf unrecognized with php exec() function

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using php to create a video with fade effects. But exec() function gives following output:

array(19) {
  [0]=>
  string(67) "FFmpeg version 0.6.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers"

[1]=>
  string(74) "  built on Dec  4 2010 15:35:31 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)"

[2]=>
  string(649) "  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab"

[3]=>
  string(35) "  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1"

[4]=>
  string(35) "  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2"

[5]=>
  string(35) "  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2"

[6]=>
  string(35) "  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0"

[7]=>
  string(35) "  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0"

[8]=>
  string(35) "  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0"

[9]=>
  string(35) "  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0"

[10]=>
  string(122) "Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/usr/slideshow/frame1.mp4':"

[11]=>
  string(11) "  Metadata:"

[12]=>
  string(26) "    major_brand     : isom"

[13]=>
  string(25) "    minor_version   : 512"

[14]=>
  string(35) "    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41"

[15]=>
  string(33) "    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2"

[16]=>
  string(58) "  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 31 kb/s"

[17]=>
  string(107) "    Stream #0.0(und): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 320x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 29 
kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1 tbn, 1 tbc"

[18]=>
  string(24) "Unrecognized option 'vf'"
}

Why it is giving unrecognized option 'vf' while it works fine when run directly on server.My command is : **"ffmpeg -i /usr/slideshow/frame1.mp4 -vf 'fade=out:0:5' /usr/slideshow/fade1.mp4"**

I am executing it with exec() function. Why the error is coming and what should i use to apply filter to my input video. I am working on CentOS server.

Please guide me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer i just tried the full path of ffmpeg directory where ffmpeg was installed and it worked...