# Executing ffmpeg commands from a PHP script

Tags: php, command-line, ffmpeg

My problem is pretty simple: I can run ffmpeg commands perfectly fine on my server from the command line, but *some* of these commands experience trouble when I try to execute them from a PHP script.

For example, the following works in the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i cat.mpeg cat.avi
```

When in my PHP script, it also works as:

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i cat.mpeg cat.avi", $output);
```

This, as I said, works fine.  However, this line *works* from the command line, but not in a PHP script:

```
ffmpeg -i cat.mpeg -vf scale=480:360 cat2.mpeg
```

Trying to put that into an `exec()` produces nothing.  I've tried with/without quotes around the dimensions, different formats, etc.  From the dozens of different commands I have tried, it seems that any will work from PHP as long as they don't contain the `-vf` flag.  Clearly it works on the server, as executing from the command line proceeds with no issue; is there something silly I am missing here?

Comment: You have to be careful off current working directory. Is it the same in your PHP script and in the command line? Also, are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Jan: No errors.  I'm not sure if directories are the issue, as any command I try to run without `-vf` works fine.  It's only when I add that flag that they cease to work from my PHP script.

Comment: could it be an allowed memory size of a script execiton issue?

Comment: @palindrom: Doesn't appear to be.

Comment: try making the command a script and executing it.

Comment: @palindrom: Could you elaborate?  Not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: Create a bash script file whose content is the command u want to exec. make it executable. try executing that script from php.

Comment: @palindrom: Unfortunately, no dice.  This is the strangest thing..

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581521/vf-unrecognized-with-php-exec-function

Answer (score 0):

I believe it' not about the -vf flag, but about its parameters scale=480:360. Try escapeshellcmd() for escaping the command prior to executing it.

Comment: `$command = escapeshellcmd("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg –i cat.mpeg -vf \"scale='480:360'\" cat7.mpeg");
exec($command, $output);` Same result, or I should say lack of result